# Joining Two Select Statments

Tags: mysql

I have two select statements to answer the question "List anyone who was running who did not vote for themselves if they voted". I was able to get the Everyone who voted for themselves and everyone who is not running.

I was thinking of using Except to join two select statement but its not possibly on mysql I am running on which is mysql5.0 and I was thinking using joining but not sure how that works with inner/outer joins.

```
Select Distinct P.First_Name, P.Mid_Name, P.Mid_Name, P.Last_Name
From Person P, Vote V, Candidate C
Where V.Voter_ID = C.Person_ID AND C.Person_ID = P.Person_ID
```

Everyone running

```
Select Distinct P.First_Name, P.Mid_Name, P.Last_Name
From Person P, Vote V, Candidate C
Where V.Voter_ID = V.Candidate_ID AND V.Candidate_ID = C.Person_ID AND C.Person_ID = P.Person_ID
```

Everyone who voted for themselves

The results should be the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your given queries, I think below query should work,

```
Select Distinct P.First_Name, P.Mid_Name, P.Last_Name
From Person P, Vote V, Candidate C
Where V.Voter_ID != V.Candidate_ID AND V.Candidate_ID = C.Person_ID AND C.Person_ID = P.Person_ID AND V.Voter_ID = C.Person_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

use `not exists` to filter those canditadates who voted for themselves.

```
select distinct P.First_Name, P.Mid_Name, P.Mid_Name, P.Last_Name 
from Person P
inner join Vote V on V.Voter_ID = C.Person_ID
inner join Candidate C  on C.Person_ID = P.Person_ID
where not exists
    (select 1 from Person P
        inner join Vote V on V.Voter_ID = V.Candidate_ID 
        inner join Candidate C on V.Candidate_ID = C.Person_ID
        where 
        C.Person_ID = P.Person_ID)
```